# Java UDP respond to broadcast request

Tags: java, udp

At work we are developing an android app that communicates with set top boxes(STB).

It all works fine but I'm trying to create a "mock" STB that the app can connect to so I can control the responses for testing.

I have no access to the code in the STB to know how they set up the sockets but I do have a simplified version of the client code used by the app.

Here's the client code:

```
public class UDPClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException {

    DatagramSocket c = new DatagramSocket(12345);
    c.setBroadcast(true);
    c.setSoTimeout(20000);

    String msearchData = "DATA";

    byte[] sendData = mSearchData.getBytes();

    try {
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, InetAddress.getByName("239.255.255.250"), 1900);
        c.send(sendPacket);

        System.out.println("Request packet sent");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // wait for reply
    byte[] recBuf = new byte[15000];
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(recBuf, recBuf.length);
    try {
        c.receive(receivePacket);
        System.out.println("PACKET RECEIVED!");
        System.out.println(new String(receivePacket.getData()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    c.close();

}
```

}

When I run this code on my development laptop (and I'm on a wireless network with that STB) the STB responds.

However, I have another laptop setup to pretend to be another STB on the same network(mock STB).

The "mock" STB simply refuses to pick up the broadcasts requests and I'm stuck.

Here's some code I use to act as the mock STB. I've tried various combinations of ports but nothing works.

```
public class MockBox {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    socket.setBroadcast(true);

    while (true) {

        System.out.println(">>>Ready to receive broadcast packets!");

        byte[] recvBuf = new byte[15000];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
        socket.receive(packet); // blocks

        // Packet received
        System.out.println(">>>Packet received from " + packet.getAddress().getHostAddress());
        System.out.println(">>>Packet data: " + new String(packet.getData()));
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

}

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable the software firewall.
2. Use MulticastSocket instead of DatagramSocket. (Note: The address you specified above is a multicast address.)
3. Use TTL of at least 1. If that doesn't work, use 2. Repeat, but don't go above say 4 or 5 on a LAN, because at that point, you're already past reasonable. (Zero won't leave the machine. Using a value too high may cause the packet to be discarded somewhere along the route.)

Comment: 1. Firewall is disabled.
2. I used a MulticastSocket, still nothing. Do I need to set a port?
3. How do i set TTL value in Java?
Please note that I do not want to change the client code, only the server code.

Comment: Yes, for most operating systems, you have to specify a port. (I say "most" because I have seen cases in which a datagram socket not bound to a port will receive packets that were not intended for it.)

Comment: specifying a port makes no difference.

Comment: 1. Start by making sure it works on a single machine (not a separate laptop) to eliminate some complexity.

Comment: 2. Remove the open/close of the socket from within the while() loop .. what were you thinking? ;-) ... and post your updated code.